# ACTION_TIME_TICK broadcast every second?

Tags: android

Can we use ACTION_TIME_TICK broadcast every second?
like TIME_TICK
please help

Answer (score 4):

"android.intent.action.TIME_TICK" is a system generated broadcasted action that indicates the current time has changed. It's sent every minute. You can not receive this through components declared in manifests, only by exlicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver(). This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not do this.

"android.intent.action.TIME_TICK" this broadcast action only be sent by the system and it's sent every minute.

You can start a service and define a action broadcast , then send it every second by yourself.